# Read json file return a ValueError: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm tried to read a simple json file into pandas (I'm using python 3.7).

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data='D:\myfile.json'
pd.read_json(data,orient='columns')
```

That return `ValueError: Expected object or value`

please how can I resolve this error to read my json file ?
Thank you

Comment: Please show a sample of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above code works only for URL that renders a json file. For example,

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisalbon/simulated_datasets/master/data.json'
df = pd.read_json(url, orient='columns')
df.head(10)
```

If you want to use your local json file, you have to load it first using `with open` as below

```
with open('D:\myfile.json') as data:
    pd.read_json(data,orient='columns')
```